# Bounding the probability that a 3 term arithmetic progression exists

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The points $X_1,\dots,X_N$ are independent and have a uniform distribution in a discrete cube $\overline{0,n-1}^d$. It is necessary to obtain two-sided estimates for the probability that among these points there are three forming an arithmetic progression.

Let $P(A)$ - the probability that among these points there are three forming an arithmetic progression and $P(A_{ijk})$ - the probability that $i,j,k$ forming an arithmetic progression. It's easy to see that
$$
P(A_{1,2,3})\leq P(A) \leq \sum\limits_{1\leq i < j < k \leq N}P(A_{i,j,k}) = \binom{N}{3}P(A_{1,2,3}).
$$
Now I'm trying to evaluate $P(A_{1,2,3})$. There are 3 cases:

$X_3 = 2X_2-X_1$

$X_3 = 2X_1-X_2$

$X_2 = 2X_1-X_3$

$X_2 = 2X_3-X_1$

$X_1 = 2X_2-X_3$

$X_1 = 2X_3-X_2$

So $P(A_{1,2,3}) = 6P(X_3 = 2X_2-X_1) = P(X_3+X_1 = 2X_2)$.

$X_3 = (y_1,\dots,y_d)$, $X_1 = (z_1,\dots,z_d)$. And now
$$
P(X_3 + X_1= 2X_2) = $$
$$ = \sum\limits_{i_1,\dots,i_d=0,1,\dots,\left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]} P((y_1+z_1, \dots,y_d+z_d)=(2i_1,\dots,2i_d)) = 
$$
$$
=\left(\sum\limits_{i = 0,1,\dots,\left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]}P(y_1+z_1=2i)\right)^d.
$$
Clearly $P(y_1+z_1=2i) = \frac{2i+1}{n^2}$ and than
$P(A_{1,2,3}) = 6\left(\frac{\left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]+1}{n}\right)^{2d}$. And we have trivial bound
$$
6\left(\frac{\left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]+1}{n}\right)^{2d} \leq P(A) \leq 6\binom{N}{3}\left(\frac{\left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]+1}{n}\right)^{2d}.
$$
Can anybody offer some better estimations or proof-check my estimation? May be I should use Bonferroni inequality?

Comment: Would you define arithmetic progression and its common difference here (as the sample includes $n$ $d$- dimensional random vectors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One first remark is that $i$ can actually go up to $n - 1,$ since big coordinates yield big averages (for example we could have $X_1 = X_2 = X_3).$ A second point would be that the factor of $6$ is wrong, it should be a $3$ since the order doesn't matter - the property you are looking for is equivalent to $X_1 + X_2 = 2 X_3$ or any other cyclic permutation. You are also overcounting the event $X_1 = X_2 = X_3$ by a factor of $2.$ Other than that, your approach is mainly correct, though you do have some errors in your computation.

This line has a mistake:
$$P(X_3 + X_1 = 2X_2) = \sum\limits_{i_1,\dots,i_d=0,1,\dots,\left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]} P((y_1+z_1, \dots,y_d+z_d)=(2i_1,\dots,2i_d)),$$
it should actually be
$$P(X_1 + X_3 = 2X_2) = \sum\limits_{i_1,\dots,i_d=0,1,\dots,n - 1} P((y_1+z_1, \dots,y_d+z_d)= (2i_1,\dots,2i_d)) P(X_2 = (i_1, \dots, i_d)),$$
since the first quantities ($y_i, z_i$) are random variables, wheres the $i's$ are observed values (otherwise the sum does not make sense). This provides an extra $\frac{1}{n^d}$ factor, so the sum becomes
$$\frac{1}{n^d}\big(\sum_{0 \leq i \leq n - 1} P(y_1 + z_1 = 2 i)\big)^d =: S.$$
Now a simple counting exercise shows that the number of realisations of $y_1 + z_1 = 2 i,$ where $0 \leq y_1, z_1, i \leq n - 1$ and $i$ is fixed is equal to $n - \vert n - 1 - 2i \vert$ - feel free to check this relationship. Thus we have to compute
$$T := \sum_{0 \leq i \leq n - 1} (n - \vert n - 1 - 2 i \vert) = 1 + 3 + \dots + (2 \lfloor \frac{n - 1}{2} \rfloor + 1) + \dots + 3 + 1 = \\
2 \sum_{0 \leq k \leq \lfloor \frac{n - 1}{2} \rfloor} (2 k + 1) - (2 \lfloor \frac{n - 1}{2} \rfloor + 1) = 1 + 2 \lfloor \frac{n - 1}{2} \rfloor \lfloor \frac{n + 1}{2} \rfloor.$$
It follows that
$$S = \frac{1}{n^d} \big(\frac{1 + 2 \lfloor \frac{n - 1}{2} \rfloor \lfloor \frac{n + 1}{2} \rfloor}{n^2}\big)^d = \big(\frac{1 + 2 \lfloor \frac{n - 1}{2} \rfloor \lfloor \frac{n + 1}{2} \rfloor}{n^3}\big)^d.$$
As noted above, we get $P(A_{1, 2, 3}) = 3 S.$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I also have a significant improvement of your lower bound, let me know if it is of interest to you.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would share it)